# Flickr module other than flickr_bricks that doesn't need API key?

Tags: files

I want to include publicly available pictures from Flickr in a Drupal site. The [Flickr](https://www.drupal.org/project/flickr) module looks great but needs an API key. This seems overkill when I only want public pictures.

The [flickr_bricks](https://www.drupal.org/project/flickr_bricks) module does not need an API key but it only lets you set tag filters globally. Is there anything that supports setting different tag filters for different galleries on the site - by block or node, say - but doesn't depend on a key?

Comment: Are you sure an API key is overkill? This is simply used to track how many requests you make and to authenticate the request. If it has the features you need, you should consider making a yahoo account and applying for the API key, from what I remember its not a complicated or lengthy process.

Comment: Yes I think that is what we will go with. It's odd though that the flickr_bricks module works without one.